# Домен в локальной сети

Tags: сеть, openserver, домен

1 У меня есть ноутбук который wihi точка доступа, есть клиенты.
2 На компьютере точке доступа, запущен OpenServer

Я хочу чтобы клиенты могли получать доступ к сайту на openServer не по ip а по домену. Через мой ноутбук проходит весь трафик по идеи такое возможно но как?

Comment: Такая система будет работать преимущественно без интернета. Для тестирования школьников.

Comment: Если эта точка доступа раздаёт ip-адреса клиентам, то можно опцией dhcp отдавать DNS, предварительно настроив его либо там же, либо где-то в сети и уже с этого dns какие угодно домены можно привязывать к адресам.

Comment: э-м-м, получить ip-адрес всего лишь, полагаю...

Comment: На стороне клиента что то нужно делать? Например DNS Прописывать. Если да то не подходит.

Comment: В смысле получить IP если задача заключается в том чтобы клиент прописывал именно домен вместо ip. Да и клиенты могут заходить с любых устройств.